# Navigation Bar can not find ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I navigate my app programmatically using `navigationController` below code.

```
- (IBAction)sourceLanguageButton:(id)sender {

    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    NSString * viewControllerID = @"ViewControllerlang";
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    testViewController * controller = (testViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
    controller.receiveLang  = @"sorceButton";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

but when i try to back from `testviewcontroller` to my root view controller, my `viewController` navigation bar can not find.navigation bar place turn into white.

here the code, how i back to root view.

```
[self.navigationController poptoRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: are you sure your VC is embed in Navigationcontroller

Comment: yep. my VC is embed in Navigationcontroller

Comment: then ensure once you were hide the navigation bar in your Current VC or previous VC

Comment: Use this to go back previous controller [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];